How to get access token from Okta?
I've created a Application with API services as a chosen option. I'm trying to get token based on Client Id and Client Secret with the grant_type "client_credentials". But it is asking for JWK needs to be passed.
I followed the official doc : https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-oauth-for-okta-serviceapp/main/#generate-the-jwk-using-the-api

Getting the error.
Please help me with steps to generate JWK using JAVA and how to configure it in Okta Admin console.
Thanks in advance.

Are you able to generate the keys in okta admin?
